# Count how many days between 2 measures is contained within filtered dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have created two measures `minCheck` and `maxCheck`, one to check the minimum date a campaign started and another to check the maximum date of the campaign.

I also have a date slicer from the calendar table, what I want to do is count how many days between `minCheck` and `maxCheck` consists within the date slicer.

So the date filtered is `27/06/2022 - 25/06/2023`, so I need to return only the count of days that are within the selected date range which would be 96 days because `22/03/203 - 25/06/2023`

```
minCheck = 
var minCheck = CALCULATE(MIN('Range Plan Table'[valid_from]), USERELATIONSHIP('Overview Table'[campaignStartDate], 'Range Plan Table'[range_plan_date]))
RETURN minCheck
```

```
maxCheck = 
var maxCheck = CALCULATE(MAX('Range Plan Table'[valid_to]),USERELATIONSHIP('Overview Table'[campaignStartDate], 'Range Plan Table'[range_plan_date]))
RETURN maxCheck
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping I understood correctly, try:

```
My Measure Days =
  var slicerS = MIN('Calendar'[Date])
  var slicerE = MAX('Calendar'[Date])
  return
    DATEDIFF(
      MAX(slicerS, [minCheck]),
      MIN(slicerE, [maxCheck]),
      DAY
    )
```